# JpegEncoder no suitable constructor found for frame

Tags: java, constructor, jpeg, frame

I have this class

```
public class JpegEncoder extends Frame
....
```

And this constructor

```
public JpegEncoder(Image image, int quality, OutputStream out)
```

No suitable constructor found for frame, how do I fix this?

And also I have this line inside the constructor

```
MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(this);
```

It says `JpegEncoder` cannot be converted into component. What should I do to with these 2 errors?

Comment: Is this a java.awt.Frame? I think you might be importing a different one...

Comment: @Bret netbeans' fault... i fixed imports...

Answer (score 0):

import `java.awt.Frame`

it was incorrectly imported